# Dynamic Pivot Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got very simple query but I can't make it work.
Please help. thank you

i followed the tut but my query doesn't work

```
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Site NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @MOnth NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''


SELECT @ColumnName += QUOTENAME([Product Category]) + ','
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [Product Category]
    FROM vw_TTMTALK_BREAKDOWN_DETAIL_LINE 
    WHERE [Customer No] = 'SLPIP' AND
    DATEPART(yyyy, [Posting Date])= '2016' AND
    CONVERT(CHAR(3), [Posting Date], 0)= 'Jan'
    GROUP BY [Customer No], [Product Category]
) AS T1

SET @ColumnName = LEFT(@ColumnName,LEN(@ColumnName)-1)

set @Site = 'SLPIP'
set @Date = '2016'
set @Month = 'Jan'

SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT [Customer No], [Product Category]
FROM vw_TTMTALK_BREAKDOWN_DETAIL_LINE 
WHERE [Customer No] = ' +  @Site + '  AND
DATEPART(yyyy, [Posting Date])=' + @Date + ' AND
CONVERT(CHAR(3), [Posting Date], 0)=' + @Month + '
--GROUP BY [Customer No], [Product Category]
) T2 
PIVOT (
  COUNT([Customer No])
  FOR [Product Category] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
) T3'
--print @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'SLPIP'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'Jan'.
```

Comment: Missing ticks around @site in your dynamic query. and around month. assuming string data type for both. add char(39) before and after site.  Example: `WHERE [Customer No] = ' + char(39) +@Site + char(39) '  AND`

Comment: Thank you sir xQbert your solution works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to use parameterized queries as much as possible and use string concatenation only when it's absolutely neccessery.

So by fixing that, your query should look somehow like that:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @Site NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @MOnth NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @ColumnName += ',' + QUOTENAME([Product Category])
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Product Category]
    FROM vw_TTMTALK_BREAKDOWN_DETAIL_LINE
    WHERE [Customer No] = 'SLPIP'
        AND DATEPART(yyyy, [Posting Date]) = '2016'
        AND CONVERT(CHAR(3), [Posting Date], 0) = 'Jan'
    GROUP BY [Customer No], [Product Category]
    ) AS T1;

SET @Site = 'SLPIP';
SET @Date = '2016';
SET @Month = 'Jan';

SET @Query = '
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT [Customer No], [Product Category]
        FROM vw_TTMTALK_BREAKDOWN_DETAIL_LINE 
        WHERE [Customer No] = @Site
            AND DATEPART(yyyy, [Posting Date]) = @Date
            AND CONVERT(CHAR(3), [Posting Date], 0) = @Month
        ) T2
    PIVOT (
        COUNT([Customer No])
        FOR [Product Category] IN (' + STUFF(@ColumnName, 1, 1, '') + ')
        ) T3';

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
    , N'@Site NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date NVARCHAR(MAX), @Month NVARCHAR(MAX)'
    , @Site
    , @Date
    , @Month;
```

I would also encourage you to fix the way you query [Posting Date]

Instead of this:

```
AND DATEPART(yyyy, [Posting Date]) = '2016'
AND CONVERT(CHAR(3), [Posting Date], 0) = 'Jan'
```

I'd rewrite it like that:

```
AND [Posting Date] >= '2016-01-01'
AND [Posting Date] <  '2016-02-01';
```

This will use index on `[Posting Date]`, if there's any.

Comment: the first i run it doesn't work, after a 5min it works, thank you very much sir. actually i am using Year in query. I misuse the variable @

Answer (score 2):

You need to use quotes arround SLPIP and Jan when you build your query because those values are string